# Description in share tooltip is wrong if user is not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, share-this

Description for share tooltip says that it includes my user id even if I not logged in (just try to open post in private mode).

> [image: no user id actually]

This is wrong and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong. Fixed locally; will be included in the next deploy.

[image]